# how to check Json file update and if updated then refresh my page with updated data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Is it possible to update my results showing on the page (view) when my json file get updated.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'hotelResult.json'
})
.success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.data = data;
});
```

I am showing this data on my angular page and data is stored in Json file. I want to update page when this Json file updated, so if there is any solution pls share.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

ngCloak-This is What you need !!